# Filtered signal does not follow my cut off frequency

Tags: signal-analysis, lowpass-filter

I filtered my signal with low pass filter butterworth forth order with cutoff frequency of 50 hz. However when I compare the filtered signal with original one in frequency domain, it seems that the cut off frequency started from 25 hz instead of 50.

[image: The comparison of the original with filtered signal in frequency domain]

this is my matlab code and my data from [here](https://box.hu-berlin.de/f/5d017ef4fbff4fdc8657/?dl=1)

```
%sampling frequency is 146

[b,aa] = butter(10, 50/146,'low');
data_filtered = filtfilt (b,aa,data);
```

did i make some mistake ?

Answer (score 3):

> did i make some mistake ?

Yes. The cutoff frequency is specified relative to the Nyquist Frequency and not the sample rate

From the documentation

> Wn must be 0.0 < Wn < 1.0, with 1.0 corresponding to half the sample
>   rate.

Also: you design a 10th order butterworth and filtfilt() doubles that again to 20. That will give you significant domain "ringing".

Comment: From https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31671/butterworth-filtering-behaving-unexpectedly-matlab/31793?r=SearchResults#31793: “One final note for the sake of clarification. The normalized cutoff you've used is 0.5 pi radians/sample. This means the filter's cutoff frequency in Hertz will be 0.5 * 50 Hz -> 25 Hz.“